# Drupal 8 error when trying to access any admin functionality

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Any time I select an admin option i get the below error.

```
Error: Class 'Drupal\Core\Form\FormErrorHandler' not found in Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService() (line 258 of core\lib\Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container.php).
```

I have cleared my cache and restarted wamp, not sure what the next step is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarted my PC and that seemed to work. I have no idea what the error is linked to, but that seems to work if anyone is having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I get an error that is in a core or contributed module and clearing cache and and server restart doesn't help, I usually try running database updates next to see if any where missed.

Have you run the update.php? if that fails you could try using drush to run the update.php using `drush updb`

If that doesn't work I would run a backup of the codebase and db then try updating the modules, then update core using drush `drush up`

Comment: I tried all of that and ended up out of sheer annoyance restarting my pc and that seemed to work. I have no idea what the error is linked to but that seems to work if anyone is having the same issue.

Comment: As you can probably tell from some of the paths in the error its do do with how Drupal 8 handles Dependency injection using its service layer. 

It was also a core module by the looks of it.

With something like that it's highly unlikely that its a bug in core (although not impossible) so my steps to take are: **clear cache**, **check there are no missing DB updates**, **Run *Updates on modules**, **Run updates to core**. Drush or the Drupal CLI are great tools to do those steps b/c sometimes you can't run them through the Drupal GUI.